# Django signals и две модели onetoone

Tags: django

```
class CustomUserA:
    user = AutoOneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, primary_key=True)


class CustomUserB:
    user = AutoOneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, primary_key=True)
```

Как, используя сигнал, понять, какая из моделей сохранилась ?

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
def create_or_update_custom_user(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        CustomUserA.objects.create(user=instance)
        ....
```

Или же использовать `pre_save`, но как тогда понять, какая из моделей сохранилась ?

```
@admin.register(User)
class MyUserAdmin(AuthUserAdmin):

    form = MyUserChangeForm
    add_form = MyUserCreationForm
    fieldsets = (
            ('Профиль пользователя', {'fields': (
                'phone_number', 'sites', 'raiting', 
                'first_name', 'last_name'
                )}
            ),
    ) + AuthUserAdmin.fieldsets
    list_display = ('username', 'is_superuser')
    search_fields = ['username', 'first_name', 'last_name']
    inlines = [
        InlineAdminCustomUserA,
        InlineAdminCustomUserB,
    ]
```

Когда создаётся `User` то при использовании post_save сохраняется `CustomUserA` из-за того, что он выше, а затем происходит ошибка такого рода `Ключ "(user_id)=(27)" уже существует."`, без сигнала же создаются и `CustomUserA` и `CustomUserB`.

Можно было бы переопределить `save_formset()` в `django-admin` но, мне кажется, лучше разобраться с сигналами.

Comment: Не пойму код приложения. модель указывается как AUTH_USER_MODEL, есть функция if. В if и определять, или смотреть кто sender

Comment: sender всегда один и тот же - User,  он же AUTO_USER_MODEL, 
а сохранится может либо CustomUserA, либо CustomUserB

Comment: код if created:
        CustomUserA.objects.create(user=instance) выполняется? Если да, то почему в него не подставить маркер для себя, true false

Comment: Спасибо. 
Сформулируй ответ, я засчитаю его.
Что-то я тупанул :)

Comment: Хотя не всё так просто оказалось :) 
При User в django admin, создаётся и CustomUserA и CustomUserB, срабатывают оба сигнала.

Comment: может стоит изменить задачу, не контролировать сигнал, а контролировать последний созданный объект по id в базе данных, стал больше, после выполнения, исполняем. Кода мало, не возможно подсказать что-то подробнее.

Comment: сущетвует ли вообще ситуация, когда два объекта в связи один к одному не будут создаваться одновременно, при данном коде?

Comment: Стоит использовать ForeignKey в таком случае ?
Подскажите, пожалуйста,  лучший вариант, как иметь 3 вида пользователей ?

Comment: для чего два класса если одни и теже данные, не лучше один класс и дополнительное поле, для разделение пользователей на типы, так и управлять проще будет. Вторая модель какую роль выполняет?

Comment: Данные в CustomUserA и CustomUserB отличаются сильно. Простым BooleanField или choices не отделаться ...

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/59719/discussion-between-narnik-gamarnik-and-igor).

Comment: по хорошему, если столько дополнительных полей, то лучше не расширять родительскую, а создать свою на основе обстрактной, в документации есть пример как сделать. Меньше проблем в итоге будет. custom User model https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/customizing/#substituting-a-custom-user-model